# who i can put TopTabNavigator with react-navigation?

Tags: react-native

i need to make a Top Tab Navigator but i cant find a way to modificate the position of the Bottom Tab Navigator , there any way to make it ? ( i dont want to use the design of the createMaterialTopTabNavigator )

[Like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbLqx.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`, it provide option to sticky tab bar in the top of the screen.

[https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/#:~:text=A%20material%2Ddesign%20themed%20tab,each%20route%20are%20mounted%20immediately](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/#:%7E:text=A%20material%2Ddesign%20themed%20tab,each%20route%20are%20mounted%20immediately).

Comment: Thanks but i mentionned in my question that i dont want to use createMaterialTopTabNavigator because the animation